# Пользовательское соглашение о использования файлов cookie на WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

На сайте есть такое модальное окно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не знаю как нужно его реализовать. Что должно быть при нажатии на "Соглашаюсь с условиями". Просто окно закрыть или кокой-то код должен сработать. Сайт на WordPress.

Вот html

```
<div class="cookie_modal">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cookie">
            <div>
                <p>Продолжая пользоваться сайтом,<br /> вы соглашаетесь с условиями <a href="#">использования файлов cookie</a>.</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#" class="blue_pill close_cookie">Соглашаюсь с условиями</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Поставить плагин, коих сотни. Но лучше выбросить из головы этот бред и не попугайничать.

Comment: А зачем вам куки?

Comment: Есть так в макете. Поэтому и спросил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По нажатию на кнопку, надо поставить куки, чтобы больше не выводить пользователю это сообщение.

Вот файл с реализацией.

```php
<?php
/**
 * GDPR class file.
 */

/**
 * Class GDPR
 */
class GDPR {

    /**
     * Init class.
     */
    public function init(): void {
        add_action( 'wp_print_footer_scripts', [ $this, 'print_footer_scripts' ] );
    }

    /**
     * Print the GDPR message in footer.
     */
    public function print_footer_scripts(): void {
        ?>
        <div id="cookie-notice">
            <div>
                <?php esc_html_e( 'This website uses cookies to ensure you get the most relevant experience on our website.' ); ?>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button onclick="acceptCookie();"><?php esc_html_e( 'Accept' ); ?></button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <style>
            #cookie-notice {
                background: #ddd;
                font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
                font-size: 15px;
                padding: 0 14px;
                position: fixed;
                bottom: 0;
                width: 100%;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: space-between;
                visibility: hidden;
                z-index: 1000000;
            }

            #cookie-notice div {
                padding: 20px 10px;
            }

            #cookie-notice button {
                color: #fff;
                background: #40b123;
                font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
                font-size: 15px;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                padding: 10px 15px;
                width: 100%;
                cursor: pointer
            }
        </style>

        <script>
            function acceptCookie() {
                document.cookie = 'gdpr-cookie=1; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2030 12:00:00 UTC; path=/';
                document.getElementById( 'cookie-notice' ).style.visibility = 'hidden';
            }

            document.cookie.indexOf( 'gdpr-cookie' ) < 0 &&
            ( document.getElementById( 'cookie-notice' ).style.visibility = 'visible' );
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}

( new GDPR() )->init();
```